# Git - master branch 26 ahead 22 behind

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-merge

Please help to bring the master branch to match with the remote master branch which has all the recent changes.

Please find below the git status:
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 26 and 22 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message showed by `git status` means that when you make local changes there already has new changes on remote which you were not pull first.

There are below options you can refer:

- `git pull` directly and then solve the merge conflicts as git message hint you, then push your local `master` to remote repo.
- Pull the remote changes firstly, and then rebase your local changes on the top of latest master branch by `git pull origin master --rebase`. But you should also solve the conflicts may occur.
- If your don’t want the local changes you made on master branch, then reset local `master` as `origin/master` by `git fetch origin master` and `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marina. Your 3rd point helped my case to resolve. Thanks again.